# Table column group widths

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Suppose I have a table like below:

```
|<--                        Fixed width                          ->|
|<- group width     ->|<- group width     ->|
--------------------------------------------------------------------
| Label 1 | Input 1   | Label 2 | Input 2   | Filler (auto-expand) |
| Label 3 | Input 3   | Label 4 | Input 4   |                      |
| Section header (colspan=5)                                       |
--------------------------------------------------------------------
| Label 5 | Input 5   | Label 6 | Input 6   |                      |
| Label 7 | Input 7   | Label 8 | Input 8   |                      |
--------------------------------------------------------------------
```

How would I style it so that each column group has a fixed width but the individual columns under each group automatically adjust like so:

1. Label columns adjust to the minimum width required to display text for that column without wrapping
2. Input columns expand to fill the space left for the group width minus the label column width.

Example:

```
|<--                        Fixed width                          ->|
|<- group width     ->|<- group width     ->|
--------------------------------------------------------------------
| Label 1   | Input 1 | Label 2 | Input 2   | Filler (auto-expand) |
| Label 3.. | Input 3 | Label 4 | Input 4   |                      |
| Section header (colspan=5)                                       |
--------------------------------------------------------------------
| Label 5   | Input 5 | Label 6 | Input 6   |                      |
```

In the above, the label column containing Label 1, 3, and 5 has adjusted to the minimum width required for all text to be shown without truncation (width of Label 3). At the same time, the corresponding input columns have adjusted so that the group width stayed the same.

I have a jsfiddle of the structure and initial css [here](http://jsfiddle.net/vin_g/Zj8z8/1/).

Feel free to adjust the structure if required, though I would prefer minimal changes to it. I'm hoping this would be possible with just an html structure change and css.

I would welcome jquery solutions as well. Though I should also mention that label/input rows could be added dynamically, and the columns would need to adjust appropriately (so I can't just set fixed widths on initial document load).

If this can also be changed so that a table is no longer required, better.

Comment: Wouldn't nesting tables in each group do what you want? Then set fixed widths on the parent table columns

Comment: It would, except every once in a while I will have section headers (as above) that would span a whole row. This would mean I would need to cut the nested table into two rows (one before the section header, the other after). And if I did that, I cannot guarantee the two nested tables to be consistent in column widths outside of defining fixed widths for both.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/vin_g/Lvy7G/1/ shows this problem. In the fiddle, Label 1 and 3 are on correct widths, but after the section header, Label 5 does not have the same width.

Comment: @Vin-G Please have a look at my answer. I guess it will help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Zj8z8/28/) what you are looking for? If yes please look into below code

```
    // Assume you want widths 60, 90, 120 widths to each header

    var widths = [60, 90, 120];

    $('table td[colspan]').each(function (i, v) {
        var th = $(this),
            width = Math.floor(widths[i] / th.attr('colspan') * 1),
            indStrt = 0;
        th.width(widths[i]);
        th.prevAll().each(function () {
            var ind = $(this).attr('colspan');
            indStrt += ind ? ind * 1 : 1;
        });
        var nextTr = th.closest('tr').next(),
            tds = nextTr.find('td');
        var $siblings = tds.eq(indStrt).nextUntil(tds.eq(indStrt + th.attr('colspan') * 1)).andSelf();
        $siblings.each(function () {
            $(this).width(width);
        });
    });
```

As per the comments code is

```
    var COLUMN_GROUP_WIDTH=100;
    var TABLE_WIDTH=$("#thetable").width();

    // reset width so we can get proper column widths
    $("#thetable").width("auto");

    $('td.label').each(function (e, v) {
        var labelWidth = $(v).width();
        $(v).width(labelWidth);
        console.log(labelWidth);
        $(v).next().width(COLUMN_GROUP_WIDTH-labelWidth);

    });

    // so we can check total widths
    //$(".header").css("display", "table-row");

    $("#thetable").width(TABLE_WIDTH);
```

Comment: The label columns (column 1, column 3, on so on) need to have minimum widths for all the text in those columns to fit.

Comment: @Vin-G Then adjust the width of header column widths array.

Comment: @Vin-G And hope you learn appreciating people who are working to solve your problem here on stackoverflow.com

Comment: *In the fiddle, all columns would have the same width (with respect to the column group). The part wherein the column groups have the same width is satisfied. However, the label columns (column 1, column 3, on so on) need to have minimum widths for all the text in those columns to fit and the input columns (2, 4, and so on) are variable. Column 1 and column 2 would have different widths, but would add up to the total column width. I suppose you can adjust the code a bit for that though...

Comment: hmm, let me get an image up so you can see what i'm referring to

Comment: Here we go: http://imgur.com/LEv41QE I hope the intention is clear, and yes I do appreciate people solving problems here in SO (I've done the same for others as well). I've already adjusted the column widths (see: http://jsfiddle.net/vin_g/3CpL7/2/)

Comment: I guess you do not need any JS for that then, you just `remove width of table` and add `td{ padding:5px; /* optional */ }` is this http://jsfiddle.net/3CpL7/5/?

Comment: Not quite. That would prevent me from making the column group widths consistent. But your code gave me an idea: http://jsfiddle.net/vin_g/3CpL7/9/. If you can update your answer with it, and I can see no other way than using Javascript/Jquery, then i'll accept your updated answer.

Comment: @Vin-G Done! Check it.

Answer (score 1):

Use `table-layout: fixed;` for this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Lvy7G/2/)

```
.col1{
    table-layout: fixed;
}
.col2{
    table-layout: fixed;
}
.col1 td{
    width: 200px;
}
.col2 td{
    width: 200px;
}
```

See this [updated demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Lvy7G/3/) according to your commented as intended picture.

Comment: Hmm, the label columns need to be minimum widths and at the same time, label 5 doesn't really correctly line up correctly. See http://i.imgur.com/K06idhY.png

Comment: Hi C-Link, almost, but label 5 still does not have the same width with label 1 and label 3 (or is it me that's only seeing this?). This was the problem I was referring to on my response to Simon Trewhella. If you think the html structure needs to be modified to make it work, then feel free to do so, as long as the same content is shown (two column groups, two columns per sub group, a header line spanning all columns, etc).

Comment: This won't work if column 2 has a cell with a different height: heights won't align